# Meteor fontawesome update

Tags: meteor, icons, font-awesome-5

I am using icons from fontawesome in my website, however now I see that font-awesome is updated to version 5 and I want to use those icons. In meteor, I have the following line in my packages file:

```
fortawesome:fontawesome
```

This does not say that I am using version 4.7, how can I update this package to version 5?

EDIT:

I did

```
meteor npm install --save  @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

I know see it under dependencies in my package.json:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.1.0",
```

But how can I use it?

Comment: They discontinued the package dev on the atmosphere package because Meteor supports npm packages. You basically need to manually integrate the npm package.

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: You can do some research, try somethings, and comeback on SO to ask for help if you need it.

Comment: I edited my question to what I done next, to manually install it

Comment: From the manual [using package managers](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers): "Reference either the /css/all.css or the /js/all.js, which contains everything you need to use Font Awesome in the <head> of each template or page that you want to use Font Awesome on. Be mindful of paths from where you installed the package from when doing so." So you may try to import it in your main.js

Answer (score 2):

To use fontawesome 5 with Meteor Blaze you just need to follow the [npm install guide](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers):

```bash
$ meteor npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

then import it and it's css/js content in your `client/main.js` file (or somewhere globally in your client code):

```js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js'
```

You can then place the icons in your templates:

```html
<template name="fasExamples">
  <i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to use the new Font Awesome 5 icons but here is my favourite.

The icons are split in to different packages which you need to install based on whether or not you are going to use those specific icons.

Import the core `FontAwesomeIcon` component:

`import FontAwesomeIcon from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';`

Import any specific icons that you want to use from the NPM package they belong to:

`import { faPlay, faBackward } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';`

Then use the icon like this:

`<FontAwesomeIcon className="add-classnames-like-this" icon={faPlay} fixedWidth />`

Hope that helps